# Is there any recommended value of COUNT for SCAN / HSCAN command in REDIS?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have understood the meaning of COUNT in the case of REDIS SCAN. But, what is the ideal value for REDIS COUNT ?

Answer (score 7):

The default value is `10`. It means the command will bring back **more or less 10 keys**, could be less if the keys are sparsely populated in the hash slots, or filtered out by the `MATCH` pattern. It could be more if some keys are sharing a hash slot. Anyhow, the work performed is proportional to the `COUNT` parameter.

Redis is single-threaded. One of the reasons `SCAN` was introduced is to allow going through all the keys without blocking the server for a long time, by going a few steps at a time.

And that's precisely the criteria to decide what's a good number. For how long are you willing to *block* your Redis server by running a `SCAN` command. The higher the `COUNT`, the longer the block.

Let's use a [Lua script](https://redis.io/commands/eval) to get a sense of the `COUNT` impact. Use it on your environment to get the results based on your server resources.

The Lua script:

```
local t0 = redis.call('TIME')
local res = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'COUNT', ARGV[2])
local t1 = redis.call('TIME')
local micros = (t1[1]-t0[1])*1000000 + t1[2]-t0[2]
table.insert(res,'Time taken: '..micros..' microseconds')
table.insert(res,'T0: '..t0[1]..string.format('%06d', t0[2]))
table.insert(res,'T1: '..t1[1]..string.format('%06d', t1[2]))
return res
```

Here we use Redis [`TIME` command](https://redis.io/commands/time). The command returns:

- unix time in seconds
- microseconds

A few runs in my machine, with 1 million keys:

```
COUNT    TIME IN MICROSECONDS
   10            37
  100           257
 1000          1685
10000         14438
```

Note these times don't include the time used to read from the socket and to buffer and send the response. Actual times will be larger. The time it takes once is out of Redis, including time traveling the network is not time your Redis server is blocked though.

This is how I called the Lua script and the results:

```
> EVAL "local t0 = redis.call('TIME') \n local res = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'COUNT', ARGV[2]) \n local t1 = redis.call('TIME') \n local micros = (t1[1]-t0[1])*1000000 + t1[2]-t0[2] \n table.insert(res,'Time taken: '..micros..' microseconds') \n table.insert(res,'T0: '..t0[1]..string.format('%06d', t0[2])) \n table.insert(res,'T1: '..t1[1]..string.format('%06d', t1[2])) \n return res" 0 0 5
1) "851968"
2) 1) "key:560785"
   2) "key:114611"
   3) "key:970983"
   4) "key:626494"
   5) "key:23865"
3) "Time taken: 36 microseconds"
4) "T0: 1580816056349600"
5) "T1: 1580816056349636"
```

Comment: Incorrect - the count is an approximation of the amount of work, not the returned size (the name is confusing, I know).

Comment: Although it can bring more if some keys are sharing hashslots... editing

Comment: Much better now :)