# redis how get the number of keys for a certain prefix?

Tags: php, redis

I want to get the number of keys for a certain prefix, similar:

```
count($redis->keys('user_*'));
```

But it is not suitable in the case of a large number of keys like this

Comment: The general [recommendation](https://redis.io/commands/keys) seems to be to use `scan()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve this using [Lua scripts](https://redis.io/commands/eval). See [predis examples of using `EVAL` here](https://hotexamples.com/examples/predis/Client/eval/php-client-eval-method-examples.html).

If you want to get them on one single command, the best you can do is

```
local keys = redis.call('KEYS', ARGV[1])
return table.getn(keys)
```

Use as:

```
EVAL "local keys = redis.call('KEYS', ARGV[1]) \n return table.getn(keys)" 0 user_*
```

But this will still block your server for as long as it scans the whole database, as Redis is single-threaded. You are saving here on buffering and network payload only.

To count without blocking your server for long, you can use [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan). This will basically break down the scanning of the database to little steps. First, you call with `cursor` set to zero, and then pass the returned cursor on subsequent calls.

```
local keys = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'MATCH', ARGV[2], 'COUNT', ARGV[3])
return {keys[1], table.getn(keys[2])}
```

Use as:

```
> EVAL "local keys = redis.call('SCAN', ARGV[1], 'MATCH', ARGV[2], 'COUNT', ARGV[3]) \n return {keys[1], table.getn(keys[2])}" 0 0 user_* 100
1) "1000"
2) (integer) 101
```

The three arguments passed after `numkeys` are `cursor`, `pattern` and `count`.

The first returned value is the next `cursor`, the second integer value is the count of keys on this iteration.

For `COUNT` value selection, see [Is there any recommended value of COUNT for SCAN / HSCAN command in REDIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055548/is-there-any-recommended-value-of-count-for-scan-hscan-command-in-redis/60056214#60056214).

See in [Redic `SCAN`: how to maintain a balance between newcomming keys that might match and ensure eventual result in a reasonable time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564896/redic-scan-how-to-maintain-a-balance-between-newcomming-keys-that-might-match/59569053#59569053) how you can use the cursor to deduce a percentage of progress.