# How to atomically delete millions of keys matching a pattern using pure Redis?

Tags: redis, lua

Say I have millions of `prefix:<numeric_id>` keys.

I want to purge them all atomically.

[How to atomically delete keys matching a pattern using Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006324/how-to-atomically-delete-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-redis) shows many options. Some use `redis-cli` or Bash script but I need to do it using my client, programmatically.

A Lua script approach is promising, but solutions with `KEYS` command fail with "too many elements to unpack" error.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

The following Lua script uses `SCAN` command, so it deletes in chunks within the script - avoiding the "too many elements to unpack" error.

```
local cursor = 0
local calls = 0
local dels = 0
repeat
    local result = redis.call('SCAN', cursor, 'MATCH', ARGV[1])
    calls = calls + 1
    for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do
        redis.call('DEL', key)
        dels = dels + 1
    end
    cursor = tonumber(result[1])
until cursor == 0
return "Calls " .. calls .. " Dels " .. dels
```

It returns how many times `SCAN` was called and how many keys were deleted.

Use as:

```
EVAL "local cursor = 0 local calls = 0 local dels = 0 repeat    local result = redis.call('SCAN', cursor, 'MATCH', ARGV[1])     calls = calls + 1   for _,key in ipairs(result[2]) do       redis.call('DEL', key)      dels = dels + 1     end     cursor = tonumber(result[1]) until cursor == 0 return 'Calls ' .. calls .. ' Dels ' .. dels" 0 prefix:1
```

Note it will block the server while running, so it is not advised for production as is.

For production, consider changing `DEL` for `UNLINK`. You can also return the cursor (instead of repeating inside the script until it is zero) and add COUNT parameter to SCAN to throttle (see [Is there any recommended value of COUNT for SCAN / HSCAN command in REDIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60055548/is-there-any-recommended-value-of-count-for-scan-hscan-command-in-redis/60056214#60056214)). This way you do it in chunks instead of one go, similar to [How can I get all of the sets in redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462457/how-can-i-get-all-of-the-sets-in-redis/59564727#59564727)

Or you can do something more sophisticated using the approach stated in this answer: [Redis `SCAN`: how to maintain a balance between newcomming keys that might match and ensure eventual result in a reasonable time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564896/redis-scan-how-to-maintain-a-balance-between-newcomming-keys-that-might-match)

Comment: I used your script why the result is: `"Calls 281447 Dels 0"`

Comment: No keys matching the pattern? Try `SCAN` with your matching pattern and see if any keys match

Comment: Thank you, it has been solved, the problem was with my pattern.

Comment: I get `ERR Error running script: @user_script:1: ERR invalid cursor stack traceback:  [G]: in function 'call'  @user_script:1: in main chunk  [G]: ?`

Answer (score 1):

Lua is a great option as long as you are not using Redis Cluster or all the keys you want to delete are on the same shard.

If you need to delete keys from multi-shards you can still use Lua but you'll have to send the `Eval` command to all the shards "manually".

An alternative that does it for you, is using [RedisGears](https://redisgears.io) (a Redis module), which allow you to write a cross cluster del command based on some criteria.

See example: https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgears/examples.html#delete-by-key-prefix