# Redis delete by pattern

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to figure out how to clear a bunch of keys in redis from the cache in the most efficient manner possible.

In this example I'm getting a string array of userIds. Each user has a watchlist of auctionIds in their user document inside mongodb

```
"watchlist": [
    "5eb81dbaecb87a4060c3d5a7",
    "5eb81e24ecb87a4060c3d5a8",
    "5eb8302ebae779466c97c1d9"
  ],
```

It's an auction site so if a user places a bid, then I need the watchlists that have the listing inside that user's `[string]` watchlist to clear the cache for that key `` const watchlistKey = `watchlist-${req.query.userIdBidder}`; ``

but in production that could be 100s of ids. Who knows. 
I've been using this library for other pattern delete examples: https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-delete-wildcard?activeTab=readme  but I don't think I can apply it to this use case.  What will be the most cost effective way to clear the cache using string array as input data?

```
  User.find({
        watchlist: { $in: [req.query.listingId] },
      }).select("_id").then((res) => {

        console.log(res);

        const watchlistKey = `watchlist-${req.query.userIdBidder}`;


        client.delwild('main-listings-no-filter-page=*', function (error, numberDeletedKeys) {
          console.log("Page Didn't Match During Bid. All Listings Pages have been removed from cache.");
          console.log(numberDeletedKeys);
        });
      })
```

Console Output

```
 [ { _id: 5eb8196eecb87a4060c3d5a5 },
  { _id: 5eb82d0c71b0a230b853bd6f } ]
```

Comment: Did you check RediSearch?

Comment: I haven't. I just looked at, but I'm finding the documentation a little confusing. Can you provide an example of RedisSearch and my use case?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61366419/how-to-atomically-delete-millions-of-keys-matching-a-pattern-using-pure-redis/61366420#61366420